# Chromedriver does not work unless I manually click borowser elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testng, chromium

I am new in selenium and trying to run a basic test both firefox and chrome in parallel. Everthing works for firefox but chrome is not working. Actually chrome browser opens up but does nothing unless I click email input and then click anywhere expect email input. When I do that my test starts on chrome and everything works fine. I am really sure that I should'nt click manually to start the test :)

Here is my page object;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import page.objects.AbstractPageObject;

public class LoginPage extends AbstractPageObject {

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='email']")
private WebElement email;

@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='password']")
private WebElement password;

@FindBy(xpath = "//button[@type='submit']")
private WebElement continueButton;

public void verifyAllElementsAreDisplaying() {
    email.isDisplayed();
    password.isDisplayed();
    continueButton.isDisplayed();
}

public void fillEmail (String userEmail) {
    email.clear();
    email.sendKeys(userEmail);
}

public void fillPassword (String userPassword) {
    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys(userPassword);
}

public void login () {
    this.continueButton.click();
}
}
```

And here is my test;

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import page.objects.Login.LoginPage;

public class VerifyLogin extends BaseTest {

@Test(description = "Verfifies Login Page Functionality")
public void verifyLogin() throws InterruptedException {
    LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
    loginPage.verifyAllElementsAreDisplaying();
    loginPage.fillEmail("email");
    loginPage.fillPassword("***");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
}
```

In BaseTest class I have @BeforeSuit and @AfterSuite annotations to manage driver.

Comment: This means that the script cannot find the elements you click. You have to search for them with a different way

Comment: Is it has a chance that it works sometimes but not works sometimes when I write correct locator ? Because it works occasionally.

Comment: If so, then try to put some sleep before this element. If after inserting the sleep command you can see the element, then you need to implement waitUntil functionality